# Access a docker containers own localhost inside that container -- php apache

Tags: php, apache, docker, localhost, codeception

I am trying to access the `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1` from *inside* the docker container itself. I can ping `localhost` when I am inside the running container:

```
$ sudo docker exec -i -t 045ff7f4755b /bin/bash
$ ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms
```

But, I get an error when I try

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1/api.php
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.0-apache
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.5.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN mkdir /opt/framework
COPY . /opt/framework
COPY . /var/www/html/

WORKDIR /opt/framework
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-php-entrypoint"]
```

The endgame here, is to be able to run [codeception](http://codeception.com) (an acceptance tester) inside that container and for everything to be contained inside that container. I am also open to the idea that I may be approaching this entirely wrong. I am new to docker, and am not sure the best way to get my desired result.

Comment: And it works if you access it from the outside? What about if you use `curl` inside the container but with the ip of the bridge (you can find it using `ip addr` or `cat /etc/hosts` inside the container)?

Comment: That was a great idea. Didn't get me far. I tried

root@43e90c20dd9c:/opt/project# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2 43e90c20dd9c

Comment: What is in docker-php-entrypoint? What process in the container is listening on port 80? Have you verified it is running and listening on port 80? Is it bound to localhost?

Comment: I tried with the same base image. Adding just an index.html (`<h1> hey </h1>`) to /var/www/html. Ran it with: `docker run -d -p 80:80 my-image`. I was able to access my index.html in my browser by going to server-ip:80. So it seemd to work correctly. After that I went inside the container like you did and I performed the curl 127.0.0.1 and it gave me `<h1> hey </1>`

Comment: Well, thank you @DanLowe and @lorezvth7. You were both right. I was adding the same `ENTRYPOINT` from the base image, and that was messing everything up. Removing that line solved my problem. If someone wants to turn that into an answer, I'd be happy to accept :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are adding the same `ENTRYPOINT` from the base image, and that is messing everything up, if you remove that line, your problem is solved.